# Как узнать css свойства по значению

Tags: javascript, css

У меня есть значение css, мне с помощью javascript нужно узнать какие свойства использует используют это значение. Например 100px.

```html
<div style="width:100px; height:100px; background:firebrick;" id="ewr"></div>
```

Comment: только те, которые Inline прописаны?

Comment: Ну да, но можно и которые в css файле, но это необязательно.

Comment: для inline есть [HTMLElement.style](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)

Comment: не знаю но 100px что угодно может быть

Comment: А ты прочитай вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var element = document.getElementById('ewr');
var arrCss = getComputedStyle(element);
for(var i = 0; i < arrCss.length; i++){
  var currCssName = arrCss[i];
  var currCssValue = arrCss.getPropertyValue(currCssName)
  if(currCssValue == '100px')
    console.log(currCssName+': '+currCssValue );
}//for(var i = 0; i < arrCss.length; i++)
```

```html
<div style="width:100px; height:100px; background:firebrick;" id="ewr"></div>
```